# What does displaying first name and last name in ascending order together means?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Here is the Question :
"List the course ID, course name, section, student ID, and student name for CRN 1003. Display the list in ascending order of student last and first names."

My QUESTION:

Since I need to display the list in ascending order of student last name and first name. I'm wondering how can I achieve both in one ORDER By clause? I have written the following Query:

```
SELECT A.cid, A.cname,
B.sid, B.lname,B.fname,
C.section,c.crn
FROM courses A, students B, sections C, Registration D
WHERE A.cid = C.cid AND
B.sid = D.sid AND
c.crn = d.crn AND
c.crn = 1003 ;
ORDER BY B.lname ASC;
```

In the above query, I can't include B.Fname along with B.lname. Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. I'm confused with the last line of the question "Display the list in ascending order of student last and first names"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple columns in an `ORDER BY`:

```
...
ORDER BY B.lname ASC, B.fname ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

.. list in ascending order of student **last** and **first** names..

```
SELECT A.cid, A.cname,
B.sid, B.lname,B.fname,
C.section,c.crn
FROM courses A, students B, sections C, Registration D
WHERE A.cid = C.cid AND
B.sid = D.sid AND
c.crn = d.crn AND
c.crn = 1003 ;
ORDER BY B.lname,B.fname ASC;
```

ORDER BY is applied first by lastname and then on firstname